# Adding a Table in an Expansion Tile in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to add the table to be collapsible in an `ExpansionTile` when the text is clicked the table appears but I getting an error:

```
lib/screens/home_screen.dart:78:34: Error: Cannot invoke a non-'const' constructor where a const expression is expected.
Try using a constructor or factory that is 'const'.
                          child: DataTable(
                                 ^^^^^^^^^
lib/screens/home_screen.dart:77:25: Error: Method not found: 'widget'.
                        widget(
                        ^^^^^^
lib/screens/home_screen.dart:75:42: Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
                      const ExpansionTile(
                                         ^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/expansion_tile.dart:51:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const ExpansionTile({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Restarted application in 282ms.
```

here is the code where there is ExpansionTile and the example of the table required to be added:

```
      const ExpansionTile(
        title: Text("Click Here to See table Name"),
        widget(
          child: DataTable(
            columns: const <DataColumn>[
              DataColumn(
                label: Text(
                  'Sr.No',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text(
                  'Website',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text(
                  'Tutorial',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text(
                  'Review',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
            rows: const <DataRow>[
              DataRow(
                cells: <DataCell>[
                  DataCell(
                    Text('1'),
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Text('https://flutter.dev/'),
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Text('Flutter'),
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Text('5*'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              DataRow(
                cells: <DataCell>[
                  DataCell(
                    Text('2'),
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Text('https://dart.dev/'),
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Text('Dart'),
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Text('5*'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              DataRow(
                cells: <DataCell>[
                  DataCell(
                    Text('3'),
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Text('https://pub.dev/'),
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Text('Flutter Packages'),
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Text('5*'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Here is a print of the required outcome something like this:

[image]

**My question:**

As I am new to flutter there are many answers on how to add tables but I want to understand why the Expansion table is not accepting the table and showing this error and what is the best practice to add this table

Comment: Error says you are pasding too many arguments. What does widget in the expansion tile do?

Comment: @Davis it should allow the table to be collapsible when the text is clicked

Comment: Add the code to it if its an outside widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Davis perfectly mentioned, you are passing two argument which is now allowed, you can use ExpansionTile's [children](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile/children.html) to work currently:

```
ExpansionTile(
        title: Text("Click Here to See table Name"),
        children: [
          DataTable(
            columns: const <DataColumn>[
              DataColumn(
                label: Text(
                  'Sr.No',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text(
                  'Website',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text(
                  'Tutorial',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text(
                  'Review',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
            rows: const <DataRow>[
              DataRow(
                cells: <DataCell>[
                  DataCell(
                    Text('1'),
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Text('https://flutter.dev/'),
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Text('Flutter'),
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Text('5*'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              DataRow(
                cells: <DataCell>[
                  DataCell(
                    Text('2'),
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Text('https://dart.dev/'),
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Text('Dart'),
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Text('5*'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              DataRow(
                cells: <DataCell>[
                  DataCell(
                    Text('3'),
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Text('https://pub.dev/'),
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Text('Flutter Packages'),
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                    Text('5*'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

here is result:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make all the columns appear as the last one appears only when the screen is rotated?

Comment: well unfortunately i could not find any solution for your idea, but you need to have more research